# Testing function calls that depend on an object returned by a callback

Tags: node.js, testing, rabbitmq, amqp

I would like to test the following code:

```
'use strict';

const amqp = require('amqplib');
const Promise = require('bluebird');

const queueManager = function queueManager() {
  const amqp_host = 'amqp://' + process.env.AMQP_HOST || 'localhost';

  return {
    setupQueue: Promise.method(function setupQueue(queue) {
      return amqp.connect(amqp_host)
        .then(conn => conn.createConfirmChannel())
        .tap(channel => channel.assertQueue(queue));
    }),
    enqueueJob: Promise.method(function enqueueJob(channel, queue, job) {
      return channel.sendToQueue(queue, new Buffer(job));
    }),
    consumeJob: Promise.method(function consumeJob(channel, queue) {
      return channel.consume(queue, msg => msg);
    })
  };
};

module.exports = {
  create: queueManager
}
```

I want to test my `setupQueue`, `enqueueJob` and `consumeJob` methods to make sure they do the right things to the AMQP server.

For `setupQueue` for instance, I want to make sure it uses `Channel.createConfirmChannel` instead of say `Channel.createChannel` and that it also does `Channel.assertQueue`.

However, I don't know how to do that.

If I mock the `amqp` variable with proxyquire, all I'll be able to spy on is the `amqp.connect` call. I'll probably stub it to avoid hitting any AMQP servers. But what about the following statements? How do I tap into the `conn` and `channel` objects?

Comment: Why don't you split your methods ? Then use setupQueue : setupQueue, ... You can then test your methods individually.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using the **Dependency Injection** pattern.

Dependency injection is, to my opinion, the golden ticket to easy unit-testing. This not only apply to this particular test, but all tests you'll be writing.

To accomplish this, you must

1. Split your methods
2. Use dependency injection in those methods
3. Maybe make a constructor for the queueManager to access the connection
4. Use [SinonJs](http://sinonjs.org) library to stub/mock/spy.

It would look something like this

```js
var channelFactory = (conn) => conn.createConfirmChannel();

function QueueManager(queue, channelFactory){
  this.queue = queue;
  this.channelFactory = channelFactory;
}

QueueManager.prototype.setupQueue = () => 
    (var scope = this)
      .channelFactory()
      .then((channel) => (scope.channel = channel).assertQueue(scope.queue);

QueueManager.enqueueJob = (channel, queue, job) => channel.sendToQueue(queue, new Buffer(job));
QueueManager.consumeJob = (channel, queue) => channel.consume(queue, msg => msg);

// Unit tests

describe('setupQueue', () => {
  it('should do smth', (done) => {
    
    var host            = 'localhost',
        conn            = new connection(host),
        queue           = new queue(),
        aChannelFactory = channelFactory.bind(queue, conn),
        queueManager    = new QueueManager(queue, aChannelFactory),
        spy             = sinon.spy(channel.conn, 'createConfirmChannel');
    
    queueManager
      .setupQueue()
      .then(()    => { assert.spy.calledOnce(); done(); })
      .fail((err) => { done(err); })
      .finally(() => { spy.restore(); })
  })
})
```

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, this won't work in the test: `var spy = sinon.spy(conn, 'createConfirmChannel');` because `conn` is undefined as it lives in `queueManager` and is the result of the `amqp.connect` callback.

Comment: Yeah I was simply giving you an overview of how to setup the unit test. I don't have the full code so it's impossible for me to tell you **exactly** what to do, but you get the idea.

Comment: But the same applies. If you have a dependency, make it so that you can pass inject it. in this case, if setupQueue has a dependency on a connection object, pass it along in the arguments. Use dependency injection. Makes writing tests much easier too.

Comment: Or perhaps the setupQueue, enqueJob, consumeJob should be prototype methods for a QueueManager object ?

Comment: My issue is exactly with mocking/stubbing the `conn` object. I don't know how to set it up because `conn` doesn't exist in the test's scope, it only exists in `amqp.connect`'s callback and I don't know how to set the stub on `conn.createConfirmChannel` from the test. The code above is the whole module, it's a wrapper around `amqplib`

Comment: I see what you mean with dependency injection but I'd rather write the test around the code and not the code around the test. I don't want `queueManager`'s signature to be `queueManager(host, conn_mock, channel_mock)` just so I can test it... It feels wrong, doesn't it?

Comment: It doesn't. Dependency injection is a standard pattern. The arguments (host, conn, channel) can be real or mock objects. queueManager won't know it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98846/discussion-between-springloaded-and-ludo).

Comment: Please see updated answer. It follows DI and is way cleaner. Plus you get a factory.